# How to use av.open to open a BytesIO object?

Tags: python-3.x, pyav

I want to use av.open() (PyAV package) to read a BytesIO object in Python, however, it failed. I used a normal x.mp4 file and a BytesIO object for comparison.
For the normal x.mp4, the av.open function returns the right container and the container can be decoded into frame list.

```
container = av.open('x.mp4')
print(container.streams.video)  # <av.VideoStream #0 h264, yuv420p 1280x720 at 0x7eff2ac89168>
for frame in container.decode(video=0):
    frame.to_image().save('frame-{}.jpg'.format(frame.index))  # which can output the jpg list
```

For the BytesIO objects,

```
some_bytesio_object = io.BytesIO(some_byte_file)  # the x.mp4 has the same content as the some_byte_file
container = av.open(some_bytesio_object)
print(container.streams.video)  # <av.VideoStream #? h264, yuv420p 1280x720 at 0x7eff2ac89168>, ? means the result can be random, like 0, 1054153136, -649221856.
for frame in container.decode(video=0):
    frame.to_image().save('frame-{}.jpg'.format(frame.index))  # which can not output the jpg list
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
some_bytesio_object.seek(0) # may help sometimes
av.open(some_bytesio_object, format='mp4')
```